# Kotlin: How can I invoke a lambda field which has a generic type of its class?

Tags: generics, lambda, kotlin

How can I invoke a lambda field which has a generic type of its class? For some reason, a reference to such a generic class like `Example<*>` yields an accept that replaces the original type (like `Example<Something>`) with `Nothing`. How can I invoke such a lambda by only having reference to `Example<*>`?

Codebase I am having this problem with: https://github.com/Jire/Acelta/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/com/acelta/packet/incoming/packets

I am trying to this code, but as you can see on the 5th line I cannot invoke the lambda because the accept type is `Nothing`.

```
private val incoming = arrayOfNulls<Packet<*>>(256)

fun incoming(id: Int, packeteer: Packeteer) {
    val packet = incoming[id] ?: return
    packet.receive(packeteer, /* this is type Nothing! */)
}
```

Comment: Please add specific code that you're having problem compiling/running in the question itself.

Comment: @miensol Usage added.

Comment: Please try to create a minimal, self-contained example. How is `Packet` and `Packeteer` defined?

Comment: @KirillRakhman what you would expect the second argument to `receive` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is just how [star projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) (`Foo<*>`) work in Kotlin.

As said in the docs

> For `Foo<T>`, where `T` is an invariant type parameter with the upper
>   bound `TUpper`, `Foo<*>` is equivalent to `Foo<out TUpper>` for reading
>   values and to `Foo<in Nothing>` for writing values.

If you use star projection `Packet<*>`, you know nothing about its generic type, thus you cannot safely pass any value to its method where a generic parameter is expected (that's why `Nothing` type is there).

You can use [in-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections) to specify a *lower bound* for the generic type, and for `Packet<in SomeType>` you will be able to pass instances of `SomeType` into the methods. This will require actual type parameter of `Packet` to be `SomeType` or some of its ancestors, similar to `? super T` wildcard in Java:

```
private val incoming = arrayOfNulls<Packet<in SomeType>>(256)

fun incoming(id: Int, packeteer: Packeteer) {
    val packet = incoming[id] ?: return
    packet.receive(packeteer, someTypeInstance)
}
```

Otherwise, you can use unchecked cast to call the method, though it can result in `ClassCastException` thrown somewhere inside:

```
(packet as Packet<in SomeType>).receive(packeteer, someTypeInstance)
```

Comment: Is there any unsafe way to bypass this restriction?

Comment: @Jire, you can perform unsafe cast: `(packet as Packet<in SomeType>).receive(packeteer, someTypeInstance)`, though it might imply `ClassCastException` thrown somewhere.